# Why does my Scrapy code return an empty array?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am building a web scraper for wunderground.com, but I my code returns the value of "[]" for inches_rain and humidity. Could anyone see why this is happening?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import time

from wunderground_scraper.items import WundergroundScraperItem


class WundergroundComSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "wunderground"
    allowed_domains = ["www.wunderground.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.wunderground.com/q/zmw:10001.5.99999',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        info_set = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@id="current"]')
        list = []
        for i in info_set:
            item = WundergroundScraperItem()
            item['description'] = i.xpath('div/div/div/div/span/text()').extract()
            item['description'] = item['description'][0]
            item['humidity'] = i.xpath('div/table/tbody/tr/td/span/span/text()').extract()
            item['inches_rain'] = i.xpath('div/table/tbody/tr/td/span/span/text()').extract()
            list.append(item)
        return list
```

I also know that the humidity and inches_rain items are set to the same xpath, but that should be correct because once the information is in an array I just set them to certain values from the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me suggest a more reliable and readable XPath to locate, for the sake of an example, "Humidity" value where the base is that "Humidity" column label:

```
"".join(i.xpath('.//td[dfn="Humidity"]/following-sibling::td//text()').extract()).strip()
```

Outputs 45% now.

---

FYI, your XPath had at least one problem - the `tbody` tag - remove it from the XPath expression.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this topic, could you perhaps point me to a source about your different XPath syntax? Or the reason for removing the tbody tag.

Comment: @Ineedsteamhelp sure, `tbody` is not needed since it is added by the browsers, in the HTML you are getting in Scrapy there would not be `tbody`.

Comment: Well then is there any way I could view the exact HTML that Scrapy gets, or do I need to just learn more about HTML to tell what is added by browsers?

Comment: As in, how can you tell which tags are added by the browser?

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but could you point me toward some kind of documentation on making XPaths more readable (like the XPath that you suggested in your original answer), because I can't really tell how you devised that XPath from the HTML.

Comment: @Ineedsteamhelp well, there are several key things to understand. Among others, if you are going to do more web-scraping, you should familiarize yourself with xpath and css selector syntax. As for testing the locators, I usually use both the browser with a target site opened and the [scrapy shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html).