# How do I determine the correct XPath?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am making a web scraper in Scrapy for wunderground.com, but many different XPaths that I choose return empty arrays. I found a different question on the same topic [(here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191070/why-does-my-scrapy-code-return-an-empty-array), which is actually why I switched my code to wunderground.com. However, the answer given is specifically directed at one exact object. How could I determine the correct XPaths for the other objects?

Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import time

from wunderground_scraper.items import WundergroundScraperItem

class WundergroundComSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "wunderground"
    allowed_domains = ["www.wunderground.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.wunderground.com/q/zmw:10001.5.99999',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        info_set = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@id="current"]')
        list = []
        for i in info_set:
            item = WundergroundScraperItem()
            # WORKS FINE
            item['temperature'] = i.xpath('div/div/div/div/span/span/text()').extract()
            item['temperature'] = item['temperature'][0]


            # EDITED XPATH FROM OTHER QUESTION
            item['humidity'] = i.xpath('.//td[dfn="Humidity"]/following-sibling::td//text()').extract()
            item['humidity'] = item['humidity'][2]


            # RETURNS EMPTY ARRAY
            item['chance_rain'] = i.xpath('div/div/div/div/a/strong/text()').extract()


            list.append(item)
        return list
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just use their API?  Scraping is bad.  http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api

Comment: @mittmemo it's more to practice web scraping, not necessarily retrieve useful information. Learning purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the answer to "how do I determine the correct XPath expression" is going to be either "by inspection" (that is, look at the document you're trying to query, or "through trial and error" (start with general expressions and then narrow them down until you get what you want).

In this case, you've run into a very common problem: the page you see in your browser is partially rendered *locally* using Javascript.  The element that contains the chance of precipitation is include as part of a `<script>` resource, which from the perspective of your XML parser is (a) simply an opaque blob of text and (b) doesn't even contain the information you're looking for because it needs to be filled in by the script first.  It's not until the page is rendered with Javascript that the the element is actually instantiated in the document.

It's not going to be possible to extract this data from the document source.